# What does it mean when it says that the sequence of functions $f_n$ decreases monotonically?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, monotone-functions

Does it mean that if $x>y$ then $f_n(x)<f_n(y)$ for all $n$ or that for all $x$, $f_{n+1}(x)<f_n(x)$?

Comment: i guess my answer was not helpful

Comment: No, thanks for answering, but I was only waiting for more answers :)

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of functions that converges pointwise on $[a,b]$ to $f$ is **monotonically decreasing** if $\forall x \in [a,b]$

$$f_{n}(x) > f_{n+1}(x)$$

Comment: Where did you get the definition? Must bothe sequences converge pointwise to use the definition? Can't we compare them without regarding the convergence?